# How to preserve class instance of a javascript sdk during page reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, sdk

I've created a Javascript SDK layer that interacts with my backend API.

On the front-end, I instantiate said sdk by:

```
// my-sdk-js.js
class MySDK() {
  constructor() {
    this.accessToken = null;
  }
  authenticate(payload) {
    const { email, tripid } = payload;
    // fetch token from backend using email + tripid => response
    this.accessToken = response.token
  }
  getData() {
    // fetch data from backend using this.accessToken => response
    return response.data; // array of data
  }
  ...
}

import mySDK from 'my-sdk-js';

const mySdk = new mySDK();
mySDk.authenticate({
  email: 'myemail@gmail.com',
  tripid: '1234567890'
}) // internally fetches jwt token and saves it as a variable to that instance of mySDK
mySDK.getData().then(response => console.log(response.data)) // array of data
```

However imagine I save this sdk to a global state management (redux/vuex), I can pass this instance to any component I like. In the component, I can then call the methods of that SDK. But since each endpoint call requires a token, I am not able to use the class methods when I lose the token (from a page refresh). Am I approaching this correctly?

The end goal is to have an sdk layer that interacts with my backend api and the frontend just has to consume this sdk and use its methods, abstracting away the endpoints. I'm retrieving the jwt token through email authentication and then saving this token to a variable on that instance of mySDK. I've also tried saving this token to localStorage but I've read its not so safe.

I've seen sdks like dropbox where they instantiate it in one place and also consume its methods in one file. But what if I need to use the class methods in different components in a react or vue app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save your token in the `localStorage` or the persistence store of your choice. Saving the token in the storage or a cookie is the only way to persist your authentication as all javascript instance references get destroyed on page reload. As mentioned it IS vulnerable to XSS (for example malicious code from a CDN), but it's up to you to keep an eye on your imported dependencies.

```
// sdk file
class mySDK {
  constructor(token) {
    // pass token from vuex/redux
    this.accessToken = token;
  }
  authenticate(payload) {
    const { email, tripid } = payload;
    // fetch token from backend using email + tripid => response
    this.accessToken = response.token;
    // save returned token in vuex/redux
    return this.accessToken;
  }
  getData() {
    // fetch data from backend using this.accessToken => response
    return response.data; // array of data
  }
}

export default mySDK;
```

clientsingleton.js

```
// clientsingleton.js helper file
import mySDK from 'my-sdk-js';

// use localstorage oder statemanagement of your choice
export default new mySDK(localStorage.getItem('SAVED_TOKEN'));
```

main.js

```
// in main.js file
import mySDK from './clientsingleton.js';

mySDK
  .authenticate({
    email: 'myemail@gmail.com',
    tripid: '1234567890',
  })
  .then((token) => localStorage.setItem('SAVED_TOKEN', token)); // internally fetches jwt token and saves it as a   variable to that instance of mySDK
```

every other file

```
// in every other file where you need to use your sdk
import mySDK from './clientsingleton.js';

mySDK.getData().then((response) => console.log(response.data)); // array of data
```